# attrs.getAttributeIntValue always returns default value

Tags: android, view, attr

I have some view, and want to get the height in pixels. From constructor I call

```
attrs.getAttributeIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "layout_height", -1)
```

and always get default value, but

```
attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "layout_height")
```

works normally. What's the problem with `attrs.getAttributeIntValue`?

Comment: what does work normally means? What value are you getting?

Comment: you shouldn't use AttributeSet dirextly but rather use TypedArray,  see AttributeSet docs for more info

Comment: I usually used TypedArray when I get custom params from view, but now I need only "layout_height"

Comment: @user3165616 so create an int array that contains only one value:
android.R.attr.layout_height

Answer (score 5):

It returns the default walue because `layout_height` is a string value. It maybe `match_parent` or `wrap_content` also. Try this:

```
try{
    Integer.parseInt(attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "layout_height") )
}catch(NumberFormatException ex){
}
```

Comment: it does not work, because getAttributeValue return something like this "1400.0dip". I know thet I can parse this string and convert to pix, but it maybe not best solution

Comment: @user3165616 you shouldn't use AttributeSet dirextly but rather use TypedArray, see AttributeSet docs for more info

Comment: I usually used TypedArray when I get custom params from view, but now I need only "layout_height"

Comment: @user3165616 so create an int array that contains only one value: android.R.attr.layout_height

Comment: I was mistakenly using `"android"` instead of `"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` based on an AOSP test, `external/robolectric/src/test/java/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/shadows/EditTextTest.java`. The URL is the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: @pskink, Could you please show me how to get the attribute value using this method?

Comment: @Vishnu see `ViewGroup.java` source file

Answer (score 0):

This answer is particular to title **attrs.getAttributeIntValue always returns default value**

I'm not sure if this is your case or not but its worth checking below case

`getAttributeIntValue` always returns default value if the value set in xml is `android:maxLength=@integer/max_name_length` instead of `android:maxLength="40"`

Here *max_name_length* is `<integer name="max_name_length">40</integer>` from resources **attrs.xml**

You can try below code to get the actual value

```
const val ANDROID_NAME_SPACE: String = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

private fun getAndroidAttributeIntValue(
    attrs: AttributeSet?,
    attributeName: String
  ): Int {
    val value: Int?
    val stringResourceId: Int = attrs?.getAttributeResourceValue(ANDROID_NAME_SPACE, attributeName, -1) ?: -1
    value = if (stringResourceId > 0)
      resources.getInteger(stringResourceId)
    else
      attrs?.getAttributeIntValue(ANDROID_NAME_SPACE, attributeName, -1)

    return value ?: -1
  }
```

Use it as `val maxLength = getAndroidAttributeIntValue(ANDROID_NAME_SPACE, "maxLength", -1)`

```
<EditText
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:maxLength="@integer/max_name_length" />
```